# How to use qemu for the image build for nanopi-neo-air in yocto

Tags: qemu, yocto

I am trying to build a image for [NanoPi NEO Air](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=151) through yocto. I have given the machine. **MACHINE ??= "nanopi-neo-air"**. And how to run the final image in qemu. What should I enable to run the qemu for the built image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QEMU doesn't support that board, so you can't. You need to build an image for some board that QEMU has an emulation for, if you want to run it in QEMU.